# Failed to read artifact descriptor: Could not transfer artifact from/to central

Tags: java, spring, maven

Intenté ejecutar un proyecto Maven (hecho en [spring-tool-suite](/questions/tagged/spring-tool-suite)) en [netbeans](/questions/tagged/netbeans), pero al ejecutarlo me salió el siguiente error:

> Downloading:
> http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/exec-maven-plugin/1.2.1/exec-maven-plugin-1.2.1.pom
>
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ BUILD FAILURE
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ Total time: 1.403s Finished at: Thu Jul 30 15:25:17 COT 2020 Final
> Memory: 6M/155M
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1 or one of its
> dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
> for org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:jar:1.2.1: Could not transfer
> artifact org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:pom:1.2.1 from/to central
> (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file:
> http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/exec-maven-plugin/1.2.1/exec-maven-plugin-1.2.1.pom.
> Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required. -> [Help 1]
>
> To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e
> switch. Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>
> For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please
> read the following articles: [Help 1]
> http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException

---

Acá esta mi archivo pom por si hace falta para encontrar el problema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>utp.javierduarte</groupId>
    <artifactId>empleos</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>empleos</name>
    <description>Aplicación Web para buscar trabajo</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es un problema que surgio en Maven en enero de este año cuando se comenzó a **requerir** HTTPS para acceder a los repositorios. Esta es la respuesta oficial:

https://central.sonatype.org/articles/2020/Jan/15/501-https-required-error/

La solución es actualizar todas las referencias a repositorios Maven a sus versiones https (https://repo1.maven.org , https://repo.maven.apache.org)

En el caso de Netbeans, puedes optar por actualizar Netbeans a la version 11 (que viene con Maven 3.2 o mayor) o [instalar Maven  independientemente](https://maven.apache.org/install) :

- Descargar apache-maven-3.6.3-bin.zip (or apache-maven-3.6.3-bin.tar.gz)
- Descomprimirlo en alguna ruta accesible y ajustar
- Ajustar la ruta de Maven en Netbeans en *Options -> Java -> Maven -> Maven Home* indicando la ruta donde descomprimiste el zip.

Comment: Muchas gracias, llegó a funcionar el proyecto en netbeans, vibras en todo compañero!